# AngularJS: How do I get the current iteration number in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeat loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in chapters">
    <div>Chapter #<span>{{ X }}</span>: {{ chapter.name }}</div>
</div>
```

How do I get `{{ X }}` to be the iteration in the loop?

To give me a result like this:

> Chapter #1: The Beginning
>
> Chapter #2: The Middle
>
> Chapter #3: The End

Comment: Use `{{ $index }}` instead of `{{ X }}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $index,

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Cont", function($scope) {
  var Chapters = [
  {
    "pid": "110",
    "name": "Harry"
   
  },
  {
    "pid": "109",
    "name": "potter"
   
  },
  {
    "pid": "101",
    "name": "Peter"
  
  },
  {
    "pid": "104",
    "name": "Janifer"
    
  }
 
];
  $scope.chapters = Chapters;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Cont">
  
        <div ng-repeat="x in chapters track by $index">
          <td> Chapter#{{$index}} {{x.name}}</td>
          
        </div>
      
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the built in `$index` variable.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat